# 7-segment display code

Tags: display, 7-segment

What is the meaning of `BitSet = bitRead(numeral[number], segment);`?

```
const byte numeral[10] = {
  //ABCDEFG /dp
  B11111100,  // 0
  B01100000,  // 1
  B11011010,  // 2
  B11110010,  // 3
  B01100110,  // 4
  B10110110,  // 5
  B00111110,  // 6
  B11100000,  // 7
  B11111110,  // 8
  B11100110,  // 9
};

// pins for decimal point and each segment
//                          dp,G,F,E,D,C,B,A
const int segmentPins[8] = { 5,9,8,7,6,4,3,2};

void setup()
{
  for(int i=0; i < 8; i++)
  {
    pinMode(segmentPins[i], OUTPUT); // set segment and DP pins to output
  }
}


void loop()
{
  for(int i=0; i <= 10; i++)
  {
    showDigit(i);
    delay(1000);
  }
  // the last value if i is 10 and this will turn the display off
  delay(2000);  // pause two seconds with the display off
}

// Displays a number from 0 through 9 on a 7-segment display
// any value not within the range of 0-9 turns the display off
void showDigit( int number)
{
  boolean isBitSet;

  for(int segment = 1; segment < 8; segment++)
  {
    if( number < 0 || number > 9){
      isBitSet = 0;   // turn off all segments
    }
    else{
      // isBitSet will be true if given bit is 1
      isBitSet = bitRead(numeral[number], segment);
    }
    isBitSet = ! isBitSet; // remove this line if common cathode display
    digitalWrite( segmentPins[segment], isBitSet);
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you now about chips like the Max7219?  It will help you handle a number of 7 segment displays (up to 8).

Answer (score 3):

`bitRead(x, y)` takes a value `x`, and looks at *bit number* `y`.

So, if:

- `y` is the number `2`;
- `x` is `53` (binary number `0` `0` `1` `1` `0` ***`1`*** `0` `1`)

  ```
                                         ^
  ```

it looks at bit #2. Bits are counted from the *right* starting at ***`0`*** - I have indicated the bit in question above.

So, `bitRead(53, 2)` would return `1`, since bit #2 in 53 is a `1`.

In the above program, the clever programmer has coded whether to light or not light the LED for each segment of the display in a single byte for each possible number to display. The digit `8` has all seven of its LEDs lit up, so you'd expect the encoding for `8` to have lots of binary `1`s in it - and sure enough, it does (`B11111110`)! And the digit `7` has only three segments lit up, so you'd expect only 3 bits to be set. Sure enough, `B11100000`.

The comment at the top describes what each of the bits represent - the last bit is the decimal point, which is never set...