# Replacing several pinMode() and digitalWrite() pins with an array

Tags: c++, array

I'd like to 'clean up' some code that involves several `pinMode()` and `digitalWrite()` lines by using a single line of an array. I'm very new to both arrays so I'm a bit confused. The following examples are sections from code that controls a 4 digit, 7 segment LED.

```
// Define display pins
// Digit pins (common cathode)
int digit1 = 13; //Display pin 1
int digit2 = 12; //Display pin 2
int digit3 = 11; //Display pin 6
int digit4 = 10; //Display pin 8
// Segment pins
int segA = 2; //Display pin 14
int segB = 3; //Display pin 16
int segC = 4; //Display pin 13
int segD = 5; //Display pin 3
int segE = 6; //Display pin 5
int segF = 7; //Display pin 11
int segG = 8; //Display pin 15

void setup() {                
  pinMode(segA, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(segB, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(segC, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(segD, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(segE, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(segF, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(segG, OUTPUT);

  pinMode(digit1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(digit2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(digit3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(digit4, OUTPUT);
}

#define SEGMENT_ON  LOW
#define SEGMENT_OFF HIGH

  switch (numberToDisplay){

  case 0:
    digitalWrite(segA, SEGMENT_ON);
    digitalWrite(segB, SEGMENT_ON);
    digitalWrite(segC, SEGMENT_ON);
    digitalWrite(segD, SEGMENT_ON);
    digitalWrite(segE, SEGMENT_ON);
    digitalWrite(segF, SEGMENT_ON);
    digitalWrite(segG, SEGMENT_OFF);
    break;
```

Defining pins:

I'm pretty sure the code below is the correct way to store the pins as an array (but please correct me  if I'm wrong).

```
digitPins[] = {13 12 11 10};
segPins[] = {2 3 4 5 6 7 8};
```

**`pinMode():`**

I understand I could use a for loop to set the pin modes but is there an even simpler way? Would something like this work?

```
pinMode(digitPins[], OUTPUT);
pinMode(segPins[], OUTPUT);
```

**`digitalWrite():`**

I could access the appropriate pin from the array to use in `digitalWrite()` like the code below but that would result in the same number of lines of code (and be even more confusing). Is there another option?

```
digitalWrite(segPins[1], HIGH);
```

Comment: Some relevant questions: [Interfacing key-pad with arduino with 7 segment display](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/30222/interfacing-key-pad-with-arduino-with-7-segment-display) and [7-segment display code](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/29159/7-segment-display-code).

Comment: Since this is about a 4 digit, 7 segment display, the most relevant question to check is probably: [How to use a common anode 7-segment, 4-digit display?](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/21608).

Answer (score 7):

> the correct way to store the pins as an array

Your array initializers are almost right; you just need to separate the values with commas:

```
digitPins[] = {13, 12, 11, 10};
segPins[] = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
```

You will need to call pinMode() in a loop; it doesn't accept arrays as arguments.

> How about for digitalWrite() where its a mix of HIGH and LOW?

There are (at least) two ways: Make arrays of HIGH and LOW values, matching the digitPins[] and segPins[] arrays one-for-one, respectively. Or for easier maintenance, declare a data structure (`struct`) of a pin # and a value; make an array of those. It's a bit more complex but also more useful. So, for example:

```
typedef struct {
    uint8_t pinNum;
    bool pinVal;
} pinInit_t;

pinInit_t digitPins[] {
    {13, HIGH},
    {12, LOW},
    {11, LOW},
    {10, HIGH}
};

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
}
```

`struct` is short for "data structure"; it lets you combine data of different types into a single named and addressable unit. `typedef` declares a new data type, and says "Don't allocate any memory just now; this (pinInit) is just a description. I'll use it later on." It makes pinInit a named data type, usable wherever you can use a native data type AND a multi-valued data type (such as an array) is permissible.

Thus, we can make an array of `pinInit`s (pin-# / boolean-value pairs) just by using the name of the new type.

Then your initializing code might look like:

```
uint8_t i;
for( i = 0; i < sizeof(digitPins)/sizeof(pinInit_t); ++i ){
   pinMode(digitPins[i].pinNum, OUTPUT);
   digitalWrite(digitPins[i].pinNum, digitPins[i].pinVal);
}
```

The expression `sizeof(digitPins)/sizeof(pinInit)` evaluates to the number of initializers (# of bytes in the array / # of bytes in one array member).

The expression `digitPins[i].pinNum` means: "in the pinInit array digitPins, get the i-th element..." (remember, this is a pair of values), "... and take value of the member "pinNum". A little more complex, the first time we think about it, but look at how easily the array reads. And a hint about reading that expression: I read it backwards: "the pinNum member of the i-th element of the digitPins array."

Tomorrow, or next month, when we need another pin, no need to update 2 arrays (remembering of course, to keep them in sequence with each other!); just add another 2-valued element to the one digitPins[] array.

Answer (score 3):

***[ADDITIONNAL CODE and EXPLANATION OF THE CODE]***

This is the function that is used in the link posted in the comments:

```
void number(int num)                        //num is the number to display
{
  for(int i=0; i<7; i++)                    //going through the 7-segments (7 leds)
  {
    digitalWrite(segment[i], nums[num][i]); //tell the arduino to turn on or off which led
  }
}
```

It is great because you can use it by calling:

```
number(/*the number you want to display*/);
```

Using a for loop will avoid copying and pasting a buch of things. It also permits you do save a lot of memory.

Then, to display a small 0-9 timer, you can do this:

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
  number(i);            //display the number
  delay(1000);          //wait 1sec
}
```

---

***[ORIGINAL ANWSER]***

Use an array and a for loop.

```
int segments = {2,3,4,5,6,7,8}; //declaring the pins

void setup() {
  for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
  {
    pinMode(segments[i], OUTPUT); //declaring them as outputs
  }
}
```

It's very useful. Do the same for the digits too.

This method works in many cases:

- many sensors, switches
- many outputs such as leds, relays, transistors

Comment: How about for digitalWrite() where its a mix of HIGH and LOW?

Comment: @zdub that will indeed make things more complicated, but if you want a *good* solution to what you are likely looking for, you should edit your question to show more than one possibility for the data to be written.

Comment: here is a post I posted quite a while ago about 7-seg: http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/30031/switching-methods-functions-with-a-button/30032#30032

Comment: For a mix of HIGH and LOW just have the list of HIGH and LOW in an array as well. By the way, be sure to make the array `const` and, even better, arrange it in `PROGMEM` as well, though that has performance implications.

Comment: @canadiancyborg 2D arrays!! Didn't know this was an option but I think it will work. Why does this digitalWrite(segment[i], nums[num][i]) have to be in a for loop? Why cant 'i' just be a variable and the code works without the for loop.

Comment: well because you have 7 segments per led and how many digits to turn on??? an array is simply faster. Ill edit the anwser in a min. and ill explain the code a little further

Comment: forget what i just said in the previous comment, just follow the edit of the anwser!!!

Answer (score 0):

## Custom method usage

Used reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33235154/5500092

You can use a custom method like this:

```
template<size_t size>
void pinMode(const uint8_t (&pin)[size], uint8_t mode) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        pinMode(pin[i], mode);
    }
}

template<size_t size>
void digitalWrite(const uint8_t (&pin)[size], uint8_t val) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        digitalWrite(pin[i], val);
    }
}
```

Then you define an array with the pins:

```
uint8_t displayPins[4] = {13, 12, 11, 10};
uint8_t segmentPins[7] = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
```

And finally in your setup use:

```
void setup() {                
    pinMode(displayPins, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(segmentPins, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
    // Your logic with digitalWrite.
}
```

---

## Your logic

PS: For your logic, you can even use:

```
template<size_t size>
void digitalWrite(const uint8_t (&pin)[size], const uint8_t (&val)[size]) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        digitalWrite(pin[i], val[i]);
    }
}
```

And define for each segment number a custom value array.

```
uint8_t zero[7] = {HIGH, HIGH, HIGH, HIGH, HIGH, HIGH, LOW};
...
```

Or even:

```
uint8_t segment[][7] = {{HIGH, HIGH, HIGH, HIGH, HIGH, HIGH, LOW }, // 0
                        {____, ____, ____, ____, ____, ____, ____}, // 1
                        {____, ____, ____, ____, ____, ____, ____}, // 2
                        ...
                        {____, ____, ____, ____, ____, ____, ____}}; // F
```

And use:

```
digitalWrite(segmentPins, segment[5]); // print 5
```